# Why does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1} = \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=\ell+1}^{\infty}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm trying to understand why this is true

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1} = \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=\ell+1}^{\infty}
$$

Comment: Both sum over all pairs $\langle k,\ell\rangle$ satisfying the inequalities $0\le\ell<k$.

Comment: Why would it be the same? Some series are not absolutely convergent, only conditionally convergent. Where is the term $A_{k,\ell}$ you sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can interchange infinite sums (for example under the conditions of Fubini/Tonelli theorem) :

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{l = 0}^{k-1}a_{kl} \\ = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{l = 0}^\infty a_{kl}1_{(l \leqslant k-1)} \\ = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_{kl}1_{(k \geqslant l+1)} \\ = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{k = l+1}^\infty a_{kl}.$$

Here we use the indicator

$$1_{(p \leqslant q)} = \begin{cases}1 \,\,\text{if}\,\, p \leqslant q \\ 0 \,\,\text{if}\,\, p > q\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Draw a $(k,\ell)$ axis and consider painting both areas determined by $k\geqslant 1$ and $0\leqslant \ell <k$, and by $\ell\geqslant 0$, $k> \ell$. What gives?